# api call limitation in Marketo

Tags: marketo

I am trying to get email(using get lead by id) of all leads retrieved from get lead activities call for a particular activity type using Marketo rest api calls. In some cases, I am getting "Max rate limit '100' exceeded with in '20’ secs" error message. In that case is there any data lost can occur?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell if you want help with the rate limit (in which case, post the relevant code) or something else. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 4):

The Marketo API is rate-limited to 100 requests each twenty seconds, so any calls made exceeding that limit will not be executed.  Whether data can be lost is dependent on whether or not you can retry the call after you've gone back below to 100/20s threshold.  If you're only trying ton retrieve activity records and not update any marketo-side records, then there should be no risk to you.